# How to trigger a state from another component In Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

Hello world I need help with this.

I have a progress bar component and a component where I use the progress bar in it.
And another component which supposes to trigger the progress bar.

Examples structure of the APP

- Home.js

  - Component which has the progress bar (Component 1)

    - Component in Between (Component 2)

      - Component where I want to trigger the progress bar from (Component 3)
- ProgressBar component (ProgressBar)

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-stallman-rjxi9?file=/src/App.js

This is an example of what exactly I want to achieve and how I imagine it. the code doesn`t work but you will get the idea from the structure of the code.

I want to perform `onClick` from **Component 3** to change the progress Bar state which is located in **Component 1** but there is a Component in between as well as the progress bar on its own Component.

Things I tried is passing the function normally to a new function in the component that I want to trigger that action from (**Component 3**) and pass that function to the button. but it gets an error "Type error this.props.* is not a function"

Thank you in advance

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track (passing your callback function down the component tree) - can you update your example to include the code you had when you encountered the "Type error this.props.* is not a function"? It sounds like the right approach but with an error somewhere during passing or calling the function.

Comment: Yes I have already stated that this is not the original code which is so complicated to share right now and I am not allowed to share but i maid a simplified version just want to trigger the progress bar . In the original code the errors appears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make Component2 (C2) and Component3 (C3) to be children of Component1, and pass `handleProgress` as a prop to Component2 and Component3 like here https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-lake-6mx7o?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

For now, you created a function `handleProgress` in C1, but you never passed it to C2 and C3.

To pass it to C2 and C3, you need to remove them from `App` component, and move them to C1.

Comment: Thank you, But I didn`t get your answer, I assume they are children of Component 1 if you looked into the App.js? Isn`t that what you mean?

Comment: I saw your solution it make sense but in my case what if I can`t remove them from App.js

Comment: Then you need to lift the state up to the App and store the progress in App. Communication is happening up and down in React, not horizontally between the components (it's possible, but it's ugly and a code smell)

Comment: I agree with u, but I don`t have an option right now the project is already there and it will take time to change a lot of things could you please show me the ugly way I would appreciate that thanks

Comment: You asked to fix your code which wasn't working, and I did it. The thing that you are asking is a different question. Please create a new question and the collective mind of Stack Overflow will help you :)

Comment: Thank you I do appreciate your answer, but when I posted the code it was an example and I clearly specified that what I want to achieve without compromising the structure of the App. Your answer is very useful not only in my case but for everyone who will face the same problem in the future

Comment: @dev01, please accept my answer if ti helped you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226228/discussion-between-dev01-and-ivand).